# Strange bug with jquery accessing window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/xxL6e2fk/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

janela = window.open("https://www.sitepor500.com.br");

window.setTimeout(

    function() {

        alert($(janela.window.document).text());
        alert($(janela.window.document).html());

    },
    5000

);
</script>
```

It just opens a window and tries to get the "text" and "html" of its content. The "text" is displaying the content correctly but the "html" is not. Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please tell us more about why are you doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no html on `janela.window.document` try using `janela.window.document.documentElement` instead or targeting the `body` tag within the new window.

`$("body", janela.window.document.documentElement).html()`

Comment: documentElement worked PERFECTLY! Thank you man. But for som reason it does not work when the URL is "https://www.google.com". Any other URL it works nice like "https://www.bing.com" but with "https://www.google.com" it does not work. Any idea? Check this Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xxL6e2fk/1/

Comment: You can't really do this in a fiddle because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy. Certain sites might let you, but generally it wont work (Google is the rule not the exception). If my answer worked for you, please don't forget to hit the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: I will check it :) But I am using the --disable-web-security flag on my Chrome so SOP is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var janela = window.open('https://www.sitepor500.com.br');

janela.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(janela.document.documentElement.outerHTML)
    }, 2000);
}
```

But this can work only if you are asking it from the same domain (sitepor500.com.br)

Comment: I am using the --disable-web-security flag on my Chrome so the same origin policy does not bother me. But you see: your example work fine but when I change the URL from https://www.sitepor500.com.br to https://www.google.com it does not work. Any idea why?